# Equal coefficients in binomial expansions

Tags: number-theory, binomial-theorem

Find all positive integers $n$ so that there are at least two coefficients in the expansion of $(7x+1)^n$ are equal.

---

I worked out the special case that two "consecutive coefficients" are equal and get $n=8k-1$. Not sure how to do with general cases. Also, I would like to know can we generalize the question to $(px+q)^n$ or something? Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: What I have done:
Suppose there are two consecutive terms with same coefficients. Say $7^m\binom{n}{m}=7^{m+1}\binom{n}{m+1}$. Simplifying the relation yields $m+1=7(n-m)$ or $7n=8m+1$. This holds if and only if $n$ takes the form $8k-1$.

For general cases, I tried to modify the equation to $7^m\binom{n}{m}=7^{m+r}\binom{n}{m+r}$ and it turns out that I need the product of $r$ consecutive integers equals to another product of $r$ consecutive integers multiplied by $7^r$. Then I stuck here.

---

Edit: I used python to check that if $n=8k-1$ is true. No counterexamples in $n<3000$. It suggests that only $n=8k-1$ works.

---

Comment: Hi, your question can be improved by including your working to get $n=8k-1$.

Comment: What II said above; it'll be much easier for us to help you if you show how you got to where you are. In particular I'm vaguely suspicious of the $n=8k+1$; given one factor of each coefficient is always $7^m$, I'd have assumed you want rows of Pascal's triangle with many coefficients divisible by $7$, that is to say, $n=7k$. But again I'd like to see your work first.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I have editted the post.